# Свойство «id» и «req.query» не определено, почему?

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, express

В данный момент пишу бэк по видео одного не безызвестного блогера. Столкнулся с ошибкой, при попытке перейти по http://localhost:5000/api/user/auth - выдает ошибку UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'req.query' as it is undefined.

Делаю все 1:1 как на видео, у автора такой проблемы нет. При удачном срабатывании при переходе по ссылке должна выдаваться ошибка отсутствия ID

Файл userRoutes:

```
    const Router = require('express')
    const router = new Router()
    const userController = require('../controllers/userController')
    
    router.post('/registration', userController.registration)
    router.post('/login', userController.login)
    router.get('/auth', userController.check)
   
    module.exports = router
```

Файл userController в котором ошибка:

```
const ApiError = require('../error/ApiError')
class userController {
    async registration(res, req) {
        
    }

    async login(res, req) {
        
    }

    async check(res, req, next) {
        const {id} = req.query
        if (id) {
            return next(ApiError.badRequest('Не задан ID'))
        }
        res.json(id)
    }
}

module.exports = new userController()
```

Файл ApiError:

```
class ApiError extends Error{
    constructor(status, message) {
        super()
        this.status = status
        this.message = message
    }
    
    static badRequest(message) {
        return new ApiError(404, message)
    }

    static internal(message) {
        return new ApiError(500, message)
    }

    static forbidden(message) {
        return new ApiError(403, message)
    }
}

module.exports = ApiError
```

Господа, подскажите пожалуйста, что делать?

Comment: У вас перепутаны req и res местами в аргументах. Должно быть `async check(req, res, next)`

Comment: Теперь он вообще ничего не выводит :( Но да, признаю, ошибка из терминала ушла

Comment: может быть потому что срабатывает условие`if (id) {....`

Comment: Судя по сообщению об ошибке должно быть `if (!id) {…`

Comment: Ой, да, спасибо!

Comment: @АртемАверкин ulbiTV, PERN-стэк. шикарный блогер)